# Error pulling docker image with singularity from gitlab container registry

Tags: gitlab, singularity-container

I am trying to pull a docker image from my Gitlab container registry using `singularity pull` (as I want to use it singularity), but I get an error from singularity telling me that one file is not a tar archive.
Indeed this file contains `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code><Message>Authentication required.</Message></Error>`.

Command that works: `docker pull registry.gitlab.com/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master`.
Command that fails: `singularity pull docker://registry.gitlab.com/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master`

The thing is that my repository is public and everyone has read access to it. So what am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to run `singularity pull docker://registry.gitlab.com/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master` without issue, which suggests an environmental or authentication issue. If `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME` or `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD` variables are set, singularity will attempt use them for *all* docker registries. Additionally, if you used `singularity remote login docker://registry.gitlab.com` with gitlab credentials valid for that repo/group but do not have container registry access you will also see an authentication issue.

- Check your configured remotes and logout of the given registry if listed

```sh
singularity remote list
# Cloud Services Endpoints
# ========================
# 
# NAME         URI              ACTIVE  GLOBAL  EXCLUSIVE  INSECURE
# SylabsCloud  cloud.sylabs.io  YES     YES     NO         NO
# 
# Keyservers
# ==========
# 
# URI                     GLOBAL  INSECURE  ORDER
# https://keys.sylabs.io  YES     NO        1*
# 
# * Active cloud services keyserver
# 
# Authenticated Logins
# =================================
# 
# URI                           INSECURE
# docker://registry.gitlab.com  NO
#
singularity remote logout docker://registry.gitlab.com
```

- Try running the pull command with a clean environment

```sh
env -i $(which singularity) pull docker://registry.gitlab.com/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master
```

ref: [Singularity + non Docker hub registries documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.9/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#containers-from-other-registries)

Comment: I restarted my machine and it worked. As you said it was most likely an issue with docker and/or Singularity version/environment that got fixed with a restart. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a Singularity image from a Docker image hosted on Docker hub with:

```
singularity build your-image.sif docker://maintainer/image:tag
```

Since this is not an image hosted on Docker hub, but on gitlab the build command should work with an oras (OCI Registry as a Storage) address.

In your use case, something like this:

```
singularity pull preprocess-reads-master.sif oras://gitlab-registry/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master
```

or this:

```
singularity pull preprocess-reads-master.sif oras://registry.gitlab.com/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master
```

Comment: I already tried this but i get the following error: `FATAL:   While pulling image from oci registry: error fetching image to cache: failed to get checksum for oras://registry.gitlab.com/uit-sfb/metapipe/preprocess-reads:master: could not get image manifest, received mediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
` (for the second command).

Comment: I think the answer from @tsnowlan should resolve the original issue. My only other troubleshooting tip would be checking the Docker Engine version in use on your host machine and the version used to build the image in the gitlab registry to make sure that they are compatible (e.g. both built with v2 API) as documented here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#troubleshooting-the-gitlab-container-registry

Comment: After restarting my machine it worked... Thanks for your help.