# Pulling from GitLab with singularity

Tags: gitlab-ci, singularity-container

I'm trying singularity for the first time and having some issues.
I have an image in my container registry for which I have a personal access token in the repo.
I wish to pull this with singularity, using a GitLab CI/CD pipeline.
Having reviewed the documentation, it advises that I should use a remote login
The remote login is successful, yet I can't subsequently pull the image
The code is as follows

- singularity remote login --username ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} --password ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} docker://full_repo_location:tag
- singularity remote list
- singularity pull docker://full_repo_location:tag

I get the following error message:

FATAL:   While making image from oci registry: error fetching image to cache: failed to get checksum for docker://full_repo_location:tag: Requesting bearer token: invalid status code from registry 403 (Forbidden)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

I expected to be able to use singularity pull on my image in my GitLab container registry. Instead I get an error message

Answer (score 1):

Check first if it is similar to [sylabs/singularity issue 457](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/457):

> I solved this, after logout of the endpoint, deleting all credentials and login again (even if it should not have been necessary ...), but the problem remains as the pull request auth and it should not.
>
> Actually I had to login to be able to pull from my public project repository ...
> So, after making sure that I have no credentials saved in `~/.singularity`, I tried:
>
> ```
> singularity pull docker://gitlab-registry.cern.ch/asevcenc/alienpy.cont/alienpy:latest
> FATAL:   While making image from oci registry: error fetching image to cache: failed to get checksum for docker://gitlab-registry.cern.ch/asevcenc/alienpy.cont/alienpy:latest: unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied
> ```
>
> Then I did:
>
> ```
> singularity remote login -u asevcenc -p "$(< ~/gitlab_cern.token)" docker://gitlab-registry.cern.ch
> ```
>
> and finally it worked:
>
> ```
> singularity pull docker://gitlab-registry.cern.ch/asevcenc/alienpy.cont/alienpy:latest
> INFO:    Converting OCI blobs to SIF format
> INFO:    Starting build...
> Getting image source signatures
> Copying blob 04c2e9b863f3 done
> ```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586720/6309), in case you have `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME` or `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD` environment variables set.

As noted here, beware of [any `sudo` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057744/singularity-fatal-authentication-error-when-pulling-public-image#comment127324250_72057744), which would *not* use the same environment variables as your regular user account.